# AppleScript prettify for Sublime Text

Tags: applescript, sublimetext2, prettify

I am looking for a way to prettify my AppleScripts when working in Sublime Text.

When working in the Script Editor, compiling the script (Cmd + K) also takes care of setting the correct indentation for the script.

Does anyone know a way to do this in Sublime Text as well?

Answer (score 0):

According to Sublime's [documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html), you can set your indents any way you like, and specify them according to whichever syntax you desire.  Post back if you have difficulties managing your settings.